# How to extract ROI region from an image and show it in a window

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

How do I show the ROI region in a new window?

I draw a rectangle inside my Image. I want to just show this part in a seperated window. I tried a lot to find a function to do that but seems there is nothing.

this is what I used to draw the rectangle.

```
cv::rectangle(Mid, Point( 140, 140), Point( 60, 60),Scalar(255), 1, 8, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the steps you need

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("img.jpg");

// SetImageRoi
cv::Rect roi(100, 100, 280, 80);
cv::Mat image_roi = image(roi);

//show the result
imshow("src",image);
imshow("roi",image_roi);
waitKey();
```